# understanding awk array with a not and without a not operator

Tags: arrays, awk

I have  a file temp as follows :

```
$ cat temp
foo 1
bar
foo 2
baz
bar
```

whats the difference between these 4 awk commands ?

```
$  awk '!a[$1]++' temp
foo 1
bar
baz

$  awk '!a[$1]' temp
foo 1
bar
foo 2
baz
bar

$  awk 'a[$1]++' temp
foo 2
bar

$awk 'a[$1]' temp
```

why the last command does not print any thing , why the last command does not take the default action of printing the line ?

I am also struggling to understand how is the output of following commands same

```
$ awk '{!a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) print a[i]" "i}' temp
2 foo
1 baz
2 bar


$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) print a[i]" "i}' temp
2 foo
1 baz
2 bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases, the default action `{ print }` is performed when the condition is true.

```
$  awk '!a[$1]++' temp
foo 1
bar
baz
```

Print when the first column has not been seen before. The post-increment means that `!a[$1]` has a positive value after the first occurrence, so `!a[$1]` is false.

```
$  awk '!a[$1]' temp
foo 1
bar
foo 2
baz
bar
```

Print when `a[$1]` evaluates to false, which it will always do.

```
$  awk 'a[$1]++' temp
foo 2
bar
```

Print when `a[$1]` evaluates to true, which it will do once it has been incremented, i.e. after the first time.

```
$awk 'a[$1]' temp
```

Print when `a[$1]` evaluates to true, which it will never do.

In your other examples, you're unconditionally incrementing `a[$1]` in both cases. The output happens in the `END` block, where you get output for each of the keys that have been set.

Remember that the structure of an awk program is `condition { action }`, where the default condition is *true* and the default action is `{ print }`. When you add `!` to a condition, you negate it. In your last two examples, you're applying within the action, and discarding the result, so there is no difference in behaviour.

Comment: thanks Tom , that explains well , but in my other example putting a ! before a[$1]++ does not  make any difference ?  you mean to say that {!a[$1]++ }and {a[$1]++ } are both same ? in the awk block

Comment: I've edited my answer to add some more detail, hopefully that makes things more clear.

Comment: nice explanation, it's worth adding that by convention the array is named `seen`, not `a` when testing for presence so for example you get `seen[$1]++` and `!seen[$1]++` to test whether or not $1 has been seen in the input before. Makes your code much clearer and everyone with any awk experience knows right away what an array named `seen` is being used for.